# Azure Queue - Reappearing messages

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I have a webjob that gets triggered by queue messages. If the job gets too long, The message reappears on the queue and a new instance of the webjob is triggered consuming the same message. That is not meant to be.

How can set the timespan while a message is hidden on the queue before reappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Queue messages have a visibility timeout value (in seconds), which you can set programmatically at any time, prior to the message becoming visible again.

You haven't mentioned what language you're coding in, but from a raw REST API standpoint, you just need to do an *update message* operation (a `PUT` on the queue message). From the documentation:

```
https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages/messageid?popreceipt=<string-value>&visibilitytimeout=<int-seconds>
```

Via .net (c#):

```
var message = queue.GetMessage();

queue.UpdateMessage(message,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452234.aspx) for the API call details.

Comment: I am coding in c# and using the AzureSDK components.

Comment: Does this set the message to be invisible for 30 seconds whenever a triggered process grabs the message from the Q or makes it invisible now for the next 30 seconds ?

Comment: You call to set the timeout (say, 30 seconds) and it will now be invisible for 30 seconds, starting from the time you made the update call. Regardless of its past value.

Comment: I am rather looking for a way to set the timespan it is invisible if a webjob grabs it from the Q. That timespan can be set either upon putting the message on the Q or at the moment the webjob grabs it.